# react sever-side rendering dealing with `window`, `localStorage`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering

When server-side rendering a React component that uses `window` or `localStorage` these browser global variables, I always need to add

```
if (typeof localStorage !== 'undefined') { // then do stuff }
```

to get rid of those 'localStorage is not defined' errors.

Is there any other decent solution to this?

**Edit** my use case

1. `window` is for its attributes like `innerwitdth`, and adding raw browser events like `resize`
2. `localStorage` is to store JWT token

Comment: by not using it or add another kind of conditional which check client or server, or use cookies instead of localStorage

Comment: Isomorphic applications generally only maintain state server-side using sessions. See [this](https://github.com/expressjs/session) for example. It's much simpler than conditionally maintaining state client-side and trying to figure out an equivalent alternative on the server-side as an after-thought.

Comment: Try [react-cookie](https://github.com/eXon/react-cookie)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON object vs window variable for passing server-side rendered initial state using reactjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669648/json-object-vs-window-variable-for-passing-server-side-rendered-initial-state-us)

Comment: @DiegoHaz react cookie has limitation of 4kb data..

Answer (score 2):

Server-side rendering means your application is universal (as know as isomorphic). For the universal application, your code must be valid and works without errors in all environments. So the important rule is **use one and the same programming interface for all environments**.

Other words there are three common ways to create universal code:

- **Use existing Interface**. Most of environments could perform one and the same elementary code such as math operation, code that process text and etc. But some times programming interface can be more difficult. For example for UI application you could storage data in `HTTP Cookie`, Browser and NodeJS support it both.
- **Interface emulation**. If the environment does not support programming interface you must create it. For example, for NodeJS you can require JSDOM to use DOM API on server side.
- **Ignoring code execution**. Your application can run specified code only in a specific environment. So you can exclude it. For example, for UI application with SSR there's no need to run GA-widget on server-side.

For your cases just use `JSDOM` (emulation way) and `HTTP Cookie` (existing interface way)